# How to use multiple ReplacePathRegex rules in annotation

Tags: traefik

Im trying to figure out how to use multiple rules in my ingress object.

Here is an example of what im trying to do. Doing it in multiple lines doesn't work, as the next rule overwrites the previous one. So only the last rule works.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: myhost.mydomain.tld
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: traefik-int.mydomain.tld
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik-internal
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex:/aaa /xxx"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex:/bbb /yyy"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex:/ccc/(.*)/ /$1/zzz/"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: myapp
    heritage: Tiller
    release: tools
  name: myapp
  namespace: tools
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.mydomain.tld
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 8000
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

So how do I build an ingress object with several rules?

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer in Slack.

It is not possible to have multiple ReplacePathRegex annotations.